# Chrome Commands API Global Attribute

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I know about both common problems that people are having:

- If you change the command keys in the manifest file you need to
  remove and reinstall it for the changes to take effect.
- Even if you do this, you may also need to scroll down on the
  extensions page, click the keyboard shortcuts link, and set the
  commands manually.

About six months ago, I successfully implemented global keyboard commands with a Chrome Extension on the Chrome OS platform, it seems as though one of their updates has broken this feature... perhaps someone knows of a workaround?  With the code below, if you load as an unpacked extension, then scroll down the chrome://extensions page to manually click the "Keyboard Shortcuts" and assign the command, you will see that you have the option to set it to run in either Chrome or Global... Chrome works, but if you assign Global, nothing happens (both inside Chrome and outside when using the file system or apps)... any ideas?

background.js

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
  if (command == "toggleHighContrast") {
    chrome.accessibilityFeatures.highContrast.get({},function (callback){
      var value = true;
      if (callback.value) value = false;
      chrome.accessibilityFeatures.highContrast.set({value:value});
    });
  }//Ctrl+Shift+A
});
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "High Contrast",
  "short_name": "contrast",
  "description": "",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "38",
  "offline_enabled": true,

  "commands": {
    "toggleHighContrast": {
      "global":true,
      "description": "Toggle High Contrast Mode"
    }
  },

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },

  "permissions": [
    "accessibilityFeatures.read",
    "accessibilityFeatures.modify"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Try searching https://crbug.com for an existing big report or submit a new one.